# Exclude rows based on column value when second column value is found

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried searching for this and I'm not quite sure how to phrase exactly what I'm after, but I'll show what I've got and what I want. Also my first question here so I apologise if I get anything wrong!

Firstly, I have this link-table with foreign keys:

```
|ID|Value|
+--+-----+
|1 |   70|
|1 |  130|
|2 |   60|
```

Now, I'm trying to show me all ID's in this table where `Value!=70`. I've tried;

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Value != 70
```

This removes the 70 value, and now will show rows `1:130` and `2:60`. But how would I go about excluding all values in the column where this has matched. E.g. if I say don't show me any ID's with the value 70 associated with them, I should only get the row with the ID of 2 out. I've tried;

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table WHERE Value != 70
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Value != 70 GROUP BY ID
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table WHERE Value != 70 GROUP BY ID
```

but none of these work. Like I said I'm not sure exactly how to word what I'm after, but any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select * From table 
where id Not In 
        (Select distinct id 
         From table
         Where value = 70)
```

or

```
Select * From table t
where Not exists
        (Select * From table
         where id = t.id
            and value = 70)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery and [`NOT IN`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-in.php) condition

```
SELECT tb.* FROM table tb
WHERE tb.ID NOT IN 
(
    SELECT a.ID FROM table a where a.Value = 70
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you well, but maybe this?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID NOT IN (
  SELECT ID FROM table WHERE Value = 70
)
```

I use 'NOT IN' and not `!=` because it could be more than one ID whose associated value is 70.

Also you coud use:

```
SELECT * FROM table t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM table t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.value = 70
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt is quite close to one method for solving this.  The `where` clause simply needs to change to a `having` clause (along with a small change to the logic):

```
SELECT ID
FROM table t
GROUP BY ID
HAVING sum(Value = 70) = 0;
```

The expression in the `having` clause counts the number of rows where `value` is equal to `70`.  You want no such rows, hence the `= 70`.  This form of the query is quite flexibly.  Using the having clause you can check for more complex conditions, such as not having `70` or `71`:

```
HAVING sum(Value = 70) = 0 AND
       sum(Value = 71) = 0;
```

Or not having `70` but having `71`:

```
HAVING sum(Value = 70) = 0 AND
       sum(Value = 71) > 0;
```

And more complex combinations.